# Suggestions for workout to build muscle fast after suffering from bad wrist injury?

Tags: weightlifting, workout-routines, muscle, injury, recovery

I had a bad wrist injury that is taking about 2 months to recover. I did do some upper body during treatment, but I stopped because it hurt too much and the doctors and my friends told me not to. On June 24, 2015 I should be good to go upper body again, but my gym membership starts July 1st, so I'll have to do push ups and pull ups until then. I haven't noticed my muscle decrease from a visual standpoint yet, and I still work legs, abs, and shoulders(arm circles).

My diet is good packed with protein and fiber and no junk. I consider myself an experienced bodybuilder and just want suggestions to build my muscle back up fast if any went and also stronger than before. I bench 165(my own weight), curl 55 Ib dumbbell, and can do 48 push ups in a row, 10 pull ups in a row. I would prefer the workout to also consist of lower body, too. I squat 215, leg press 410, and can do 75 bodyweight squats in a row.

Any advice?

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  You say _I haven't noticed my muscle decrease_, but, yet you want to "build muscle fast".  Why would you not want to stay with whatever you've been doing?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get to the gym, I suggest using some bodyweight exercises. For the lower body, pistol squats are a challenging exercise to provide the stimulus and time under tension to cause gains. To complete the legs, if you can support your heels and can grab a swiss exercise ball, this will allow you to a supported version of a leg curl - an advanced exercise and a challenge for the strongest of people.

Handstand presses are another beast of an exercise. If you can do more than 5 then you are in a good place physically, again, a very challenging exercise for most. One arm pressups, with and without the other arm partially supporting between them provide enough progression to challenge your pecs and triceps. A variation on the pullups is to add a partial rep on each one at the top. To work the grip, one arm bar hangs will test your mettle. My current record is almost a minute. Good luck

Answer (score -1):

Get yourself a pair of quality wrist wraps. [Inzer](http://www.inzernet.com/search_results_wraps.asp?txtsearchParamTxt=&txtsearchParamCat=5&txtsearchParamType=ALL&txtsearchParamMan=ALL&txtsearchParamVen=ALL&txtFromSearch=fromSearch&iLevel=1), APT, [Titan](http://www.titansupport.com/products/wraps/wrist-wraps), Overkill - basically any powerlifting company manufactures a set as well as just about every new comer into the apparel industry these days.

I use Overkill now and they're the best quality I've found by far. But before Overkill came along I used a set of [APT Convicts](https://www.prowriststraps.com/product-category/wrist-wraps/) which will probably be easier for you to track down as Overkill is still fairly exclusive without an online order yet

Then just go back to doing what you were doing. Use the wrist wraps on pressing (Bench, Incline Bench, Dips, Shoulder Press, etc). You might also find it more comfortable to use a **false grip** for a while - that depends on how the wrist was injured and what causes it pain.